# Understanding this Lua snippit

Tags: lua, code-snippets, require

I've got this bit of code here:

```
local http = require("socket.http")
```

I know it's supposed to allow me to use some stuff from somewhere else but I have a couple of questions.

Where does it expect to find "socket.http"?
What should it expect?  A DLL?  A Lua script?  Both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`require` can load both DLLs and libraries written in Lua. It looks for them using `package.path` and `package.cpath`, in that order. For details, see the [Lua reference manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-require).

Comment: So where is it searching (in the directory) for this library?  I'm trying to use the LuaSocket library with an already compiled program that uses LuaJava to implement Lua.

Comment: #DalexL: He linked you directly to where it describes how Lua finds DLLs or Lua-based modules. The only other thing he could have done more is copy-and-paste it here for you.

Comment: @DalexL, another way to learn how `require` works is to force an error. Try `require"dummy"` and read the error messages.